# Java JDBC Sybase JConnect

Tags: java, jdbc

I need to connect to my SQL Anywhere 11 (Sybase) database using the JConnect(jConn3.jar) driver from sybase from my Java application. I have tried the documentation and contacted the technical support, but valid help has been naught :(. Also if  anyone maybe knows how to connect to Crystal Reports XI using this driver, help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You gotta give us more than "it doesn't work".  Have you got some source code and a stacktrace?  Get it up here!  You might want to include the commandline too.  Figuring out the JDBC connection string is the worse part of JDBC.  You've come to the right place, but you've got to give us more.

Comment: sorry, I think you misunderstood when I said "connect to my SQL anywhere 11(Sybase) database"... What I meant was that I want to connect to a SQL Anywhere 11 database, not MySQL database, sorry for the misleading context. Also I figured the classpath part out, Thanx alot Bob. However, I want to ask aswell, is it maybe possible to put the jConn3.jar inside my project(as a library) and dynamically load it as my app starts?If so,how would I go about that?

Comment: what kind of application is it? Web or standalone?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your jconn3.jar is on the classpath of your application. Then use your jdbc driver as following:

```
   try {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
       String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/coffeebreak";
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "password");

       // Do your stuff

       conn.close();
   } catch (Exception ex) {
   ...
   }
```

Your comment on my answer helped. We encountered this kind of problem too. Our project used the viewer in a JSP. The problem occured while drilling down our report.
When you open your report the first time, the viewer generates an identifier for your report. You have to store that in the session so when you drill down, you can use this identifier. This way, you indicate that it is still the same report and the viewer will use the same datasource.
Here is a piece of code, which should be clearer than text:

```
// Report viewer
CrystalReportViewer crystalViewer = new CrystalReportViewer();

// Key to store the report source
String reportSourceSessionKey = "anyKeyYouWant";
Object reportSource = null;

// Get the report name passed in parameter
String reportName = request.getParameter("report");
if (reportName != null) {
    // Build your report
    ReportClientDocument reportClientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();

    // ...

    // Store de report source
    reportSource = reportClientDoc.getReportSource();
    session.setAttribute(reportSourceSessionKey, reportSource);

    // Close the report document
    reportClientDoc.close();
} else {
    reportSource = session.getAttribute(reportSourceSessionKey);
}

// Set the source of the viewer
crystalViewer.setReportSource(reportSource);

....
```

This solved our JNDI problem. Hope it does it for you.

Comment: Hi ouapdouap, Thanx for the answer:).However please read my top comment. Aswel, that site didnt help me at all, I have been to it non stop for the past 3 weeks:(. The problem is, for some reason, when I open a report using the ReportViewer, it shows the data already inside the report and not updated from the DB. When I say refresh()...it doesnt do anything, no error ,no nothing, like it just skips over it...But when I try to refresh inside the viewer, it throw a JNDI name error...my hair is busy falling out :o...from sigh,lol